# Error while trying to use jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

I am new to mobile application development. I am trying use the jquery dialog in my application. I know to load the jquery dialog using href and data-rel. But i want to load the jquery dialog when i click the button 5 times. What should i do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var count = 0;  
$("#button").click(function() {  
    count++; 
    if(count==5){
        //load jquery dialog here
    }
}
```

Comment: what if he wants to see the dialog again by clicking button 5 times??

Comment: how to open the dialog dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

```
var count=0;
$('#button').click(function(){
    count++;
    if(count==5){
       count=0;
      //display dialog
    } 
})
```